# How to pass a local exception object to a class?

Tags: exception, abap

I want to pass an error local object in a class method which will display a detail error to the user.

This is the current code:

```
CATCH cx_root INTO lcx_general_error.
  DATA(lv_longtext) = lcx_general_error->get_longtext( ).
  lcx_general_error->get_source_position(
            IMPORTING
                program_name    = lv_program_name
                include_name    = lv_include_name
                source_line    = lv_program_line
                ).
  DATA(lv_program_include) = |{ lv_program_name }/ { lv_include_name }|.
  DATA(lv_length_message) = strlen( lv_longtext ).
  DATA(lv_error_message1) = lv_longtext(50).
  IF lv_length_message > 50.
    DATA(lv_remaining) = lv_length_message - 50.
    DATA(lv_error_message2) = lv_longtext+50(lv_remaining).
  ENDIF.

  MESSAGE e001 WITH lv_error_message1 lv_error_message2
                    lv_program_include
                    lv_program_line.
```

Instead, I want to create a class method and pass any local object that refers to any error and display the error detail message:

```
CATCH cx_root INTO lcx_general_error.
  lo_fi_uploads->display_error( lcx_general_error ).
```

How to create and use this parameter in the local class?

Comment: I have edited a little bit your question. Could you verify whether my edit didn't change the essence of your question?

Comment: Couldn't this exception object of a local class simply implement a global interface with the methods you want?

Comment: Interesting question!  I'm curious about how to implement custom exception handlers and pass exception instances around.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is, you simply need to create a method with signature `METHODS display_error IMPORTING any_exception_object TYPE REF TO cx_root.` NB: the prefix `lcx` is generally used for naming the local exception classes, you shouldn't use it to name an exception object (in your case, rename `lcx_general_error` into `lo_general_error` which is declared `DATA lo_general_error TYPE REF TO cx_root`).

Comment: This is what I did for now Sandra. But what if I want to pass another more specific error e.g.CX_SY_CONVERSION_NO_NUMBER? Thanks

Comment: When a parameter is to be an instance of a given class, you can pass an instance of this class or any of its subclasses (in my previous comment, the type of parameter is the class CX_ROOT, so any subclass of CX_ROOT can be passed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are regular classes with regular object instances, so declare them like any other object parameter:

```
METHODS display_error
  IMPORTING
    exception TYPE REF TO cx_root.
```

In the method’s implementation you can then paste the code you already have:

```
METHOD display_error.

  DATA(lv_longtext) = exception->get_longtext( ).
  exception->get_source_position(
        IMPORTING
            program_name    = DATA(lv_program_name)
            include_name    = DATA(lv_include_name)
            source_line    = DATA(lv_program_line)
            ).
  DATA(lv_program_include) = |{ lv_program_name }/ { lv_include_name }|.
  DATA(lv_length_message) = strlen( lv_longtext ).
  DATA(lv_error_message1) = lv_longtext(50).
  IF lv_length_message > 50.
    DATA(lv_remaining) = lv_length_message - 50.
    DATA(lv_error_message2) = lv_longtext+50(lv_remaining).
  ENDIF.

  MESSAGE e001 WITH lv_error_message1 lv_error_message2
                lv_program_include
                lv_program_line.

ENDMETHOD.
```

People often fear that working with exceptions might accidentally trigger them. That won’t happen. As long as you do not invoke the RAISE statement, exceptions are really quite ordinary objects. You can even instantiate them with NEW without triggering them.